# Python - How to partial match elements in listA to rows in listB

Tags: python

I have 2 lists, one with jobs and one with data.

```
jobs = [
  'P01_TEST1_C', 
  'P01_TEST3_B', 
  'P01_TEST5_F', 
  'P01_QUALITY_C'
]

data = [
  ['JOB','X01_TEST1_C', 'NAME', 'DATE', 'EXTRADATA'],
  ['JOB','P01_TEST3_C', 'NAME', 'DATE', 'EXTRADATA'],
  ['JOB','X01_TEST1002_C', 'NAME', 'DATE', 'EXTRADATA'],
  ['JOB','X01_TEST4231_C', 'NAME', 'DATE', 'EXTRAP01_TEST5_FDATA']
]
```

I want to find the lines in data that have jobs. The first 3 characters in jobs don't matter so

answer I want would be =

```
['JOB','X01_TEST1_C', 'NAME', 'DATE', 'EXTRADATA'] #matching on P01_TEST1_C

['JOB','P01_TEST3_B', 'NAME', 'DATE', 'EXTRADATA'] # matching on P01_TEST3_B

['JOB','X01_TEST4231_C', 'NAME', 'DATE', 'EXTRAP01_TEST5_FDATA']] #matching on the P01_TEST5_F in between the EXTRADATA
```

If I use the below it matches if I make it exact but wouldn't find the name within the EXTRADATA

```
jobs = ['X01_TEST1_C','P01_TEST3_B C']

newest = [s for s in rows if any(rows in s for rows in jobs)]
```

but what I think I want to do is search data for
`['_TEST1_C', '_TEST3_B', '_TEST5_F', '_QUALITY_C']`
but with * wildcards

( I have removed the front part with

```
for i in jobs:
    i = i[3:]
```

)

Any help greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: what is `NAME` , `DATE` , `EXTRADATA`  ...  these are variables in the nested lists, but not referenced in the example ?

Comment: Sorry, these should be string examples. 'NAME' being 'BOB' or 'HELEN'

Answer (score 0):

The slice approach that you initiated works if you followed it through to the `jobs` list with an **additional nested for loop**. You can then compare the slices `j[3:] == k[3:]` which represent `data[3:] == jobs[3:]`.

there were a few undefined variables so i just assigned them values for the purpose of the question:

```
NAME='hello'
DATE = '1 jan 2000'
EXTRADATA = 'world'
EXTRAP01_TEST5_FDATA = ''
```

An now here is the solution:

```
jobs = ['P01_TEST1_C', 'P01_TEST3_B', 'P01_TEST5_F', 'P01_QUALITY_C']
data = [['JOB','X01_TEST1_C', NAME, DATE, EXTRADATA],['JOB','P01_TEST3_C', NAME, DATE, EXTRADATA],['JOB','X01_TEST1002_C', NAME, DATE, EXTRADATA],['JOB','X01_TEST4231_C', NAME, DATE, EXTRAP01_TEST5_FDATA]]

for i in data:
    for j in i:
        s = j[3:]
        for k in jobs:
            if j[3:] == k[3:]:
                print('found', j[3:])
```

which returns:

```
found _TEST1_C
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a substring of each entry's "job" is "in" `jobs` if we limit each of those to the corresponding substring. A generator expression will give us the substrings of the entries in `jobs`.

```
[d for d in data 
   if d[1][3:] in (j[3:] for j in jobs)]
```

If you don't want to generate the "wildcards" on each iteration:

```
wildcards = [j[3:] for j in jobs]

[d for d in data if d[0][3:] in wildcards]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this does work matching the 2 column.  How would I do this for jobs hidden in text within the last column? I had incorrectly left it as a variable when I first asked but it was meant to be in string.

example row 
['JOB','X01_TEST4231_C', 'NAME', 'DATE', 'EXTRAP01_TEST5_FDATA']]
How would I find 'TEST5_F' within 'EXTRAP01_TEST5_FDATA'